# Error when trying to upload React build artifacts to S3 using AWS CLI in Dockerfile

Tags: reactjs, docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, aws-cli

I am trying to automate the process of building a React application inside a Docker container and then uploading the build artifacts to an S3 bucket using the AWS CLI within the Dockerfile. However, I'm encountering an error when attempting to run `docker-compose up`

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Use AWS CLI version 2 image for uploading to S3
FROM amazon/aws-cli:2.4.9

# Copy the build artifacts from the builder stage to this new stage
COPY --from=builder /app/build /build

# The bucket name and (optional) path where you want to upload the build files
ENV BUCKET_NAME=product-build

# Run AWS CLI command to sync files to your S3 bucket
CMD ["sh", "-c", "aws s3 sync /build s3://${BUCKET_NAME} --delete"]
```

And here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  product-build:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    stdin_open: true
```

And my .env file contains:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, the build process seems to complete successfully. However, upon running `docker-compose up`, the container fails to start with the following error:

```
Container react-app-product-build-1  Recreate
Container react-app-product-build-1  Recreated
Attaching to react-app-product-build-1
react-app-product-build-1  |
react-app-product-build-1  | usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
react-app-product-build-1  | To see help text, you can run:
react-app-product-build-1  |
react-app-product-build-1  |   aws help
react-app-product-build-1  |   aws <command> help
react-app-product-build-1  |   aws <command> <subcommand> help
react-app-product-build-1  |
react-app-product-build-1  | aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are: [list of valid AWS CLI commands]
react-app-product-build-1 exited with code 252
```

It seems like the AWS CLI is not recognizing the command properly within the Docker container, even though it should be available. How can I resolve this issue and successfully upload my build artifacts to S3 using the AWS CLI within my Dockerfile?

Thanks in advance for any insights or solutions you can provide!

Comment: I might not use Docker or Compose here: your final image is intended to be run exactly once, and it's not a long-running container.  Can you build the application locally and use the `aws` CLI locally?  This would also avoid some issues around managing AWS credentials (pasting them in plain text into a file isn't typically a best practice).

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidMaze for your help! I was able to use the AWS CLI locally without any issues but encountered difficulties when trying to use it within a Docker container using an AWS image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/demystifying-entrypoint-cmd-docker/) (which I think are explaining this particular case better than Docker docs):

> Let’s start with an example. Here’s a Dockerfile snippet that has both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, both specified as arrays:
>
> ```
>  ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/chamber", "exec", "production", "--"]
>  CMD ["/bin/service", "-d"]
> ```
>
> Putting these together, the default arguments to the container will be
> `["/bin/chamber", "exec", "production", "--", "/bin/service", "-d"]`.

This is exactly what's happening here.

The docker image that you're using is built out of this [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/layers/amazon/aws-cli/2.4.9/images/sha256-3d5f8c8ba375458f5cf1c0916c18034dbc84f6578676bd60f1edf1840ff3e8eb?context=explore) which provides an `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/aws"]
```

Then you provide a `CMD`:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "aws s3 sync /build s3://${BUCKET_NAME} --delete"]
```

These two parameters get combined, resulting in `/usr/local/bin/aws sh -c "aws s3 sync /build s3://${BUCKET_NAME} --delete"`, which is not a valid AWS CLI command.

Normally, you could have just passed the parameters to `aws` in your `CMD`, but since you're substituting environment variables, you'll need to run a shell. You can do that by ditching `CMD` and overriding the entrypoint altogether:

```
ENTRYPOINT sh -c "aws s3 sync /build s3://${BUCKET_NAME} --delete"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Quassnoi for your help!